# What is this bulb with a fuzzy purple and green flower head?

Tags: identification, bulbs

The bulb was small and white at first. Now there's this mixture of purple and green fuzziness of the flowers that's going to bloom. Any ideas what it might be? A friend found it and I just decided to plant it.

[image]

Comment: Haha, looks like a mildewed hyacinth.

Comment: Sure its a bulb and not a bromeliad?  Are the leaves soft? Or like a pineapple's leaves?

Comment: My vote is a bromeliad also, or other similar looking epiphyte.

Comment: Hi Jessica! We haven't seen you around, and are wondering about this plant. Did that flower ever open or did it just fall off? if you figured out what it is, we'd love to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Might be one of the Alliums - there's one called 'Gladiator' which produces fuzzy looking flowers, more so when not fully open. The leaves usually start dying back as the flower arrives, so if the ends of the leaves you've got are still fully healthy and not showing signs of browning or shrivelling, maybe not. The flower heads on alliums are either spherical or oval - this one just looks a bit lumpy at this stage, so hard to be sure.